# Android Open camera from a Service

Tags: android, service, camera

I have searched online and couldn't find an answer.
I know that when you open a camera in android you must have a surface view, but is there any way i can open a camera from a service?
or view the camera output inside an activity and than send the camera instance to a service?

Comment: Your requirement is too **Big**.

Comment: Well , thats wasn't very helpful.. I know that there is a way to do this , i just dont know how

Comment: use a local bound service

Comment: Any example on how to do it with camera?